# How can i implement re-entrancy in ink! smart contracts?

Tags: ink, solidity

I am trying to solve the following problem statement:-
Contract A(*func1*) -> Contract A(*func2*) -> Contract B(*funcB*)

so, *func1* will call *func2* and then *func2* will invoke multiple calls on different B contracts as per the payload. If any contract B call will revert, I need to revert all previous execution happened on contract B'. But at the same time some acknowledgement needs to be updated on Contract A.

So, Just like in solidity I am reverting from *func2* and receiving that success flag in *func1* and then performing the business logic.
So, How can i implement same *func1* to *func2* implementation in ink smart contracts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pallet-contract` has a build in re-entrancy detection and re-entrancy is prevented by default. Indeed, you can allow for re-entrancy by setting the correct `CallFlags`, see:

https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/struct.CallFlags.html

I'd advise you to check how cross contract calls are build in the upgradable contracts example:

https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/examples/upgradeable-contracts/forward-calls/lib.rs#L72

Just that you need to set `.allow_reentry(true)` flag in addition when building the cross-contract call.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [call_builder](https://github.com/AstarNetwork/astar-wasm-contracts-examples/blob/5c6312ec1492f1d018508103408690b6391e997e/uniswap-v2/logics/impls/pair/pair.rs#L316) to allow reentrancy